# What is the purpose of "::#" in a string returned from a RequestMethod?

Tags: java, spring, controller

In my project, in a method  I see a following return statement :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, params="part=category-fieldset")
public String partCategoryFieldset(@PathVariable String language, Model model) {
    CategoryTree categoryTree = categoryService.readCategoryTree(language);
    model.addAttribute("categoryTree", categoryTree);
    return "/article/create::#category-fieldset";
}
```

So, i would like to ask: What is the purpose of double colon and sharp sign in return statement? What does this mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Which rendering framework do you use, JSP, JSF, (Tiles), thymeleaf, ... . Please post the configuration of your rendering framework in spring(xml), the `::#` must been related to this.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. It's Thymeleaf framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! I finded the answer for me. It's Thymeleaf Framwwork.
[at here](http://thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html)

Comment: More precise: it is the Thymeleaf syntax for specify fragments in spring controller return values: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html - chapter "11.2 Specifying fragments in controller return values"

Comment: it would be nice when you improve your answer a bit, so that somebody how has the same question and find this stackoverflow-question and answer would know what `:;#` is about (not only that it is any Thymeleaf function, but which)